# How do I remove this shower handle?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, cartridge, stuck

I'm hoping that somebody can help show me how to take apart the this shower leaky faucet (and matching bathroom sink faucets).

[image]

I didn't find any set screws but I was able to twist off the cap (counter-clockwise) but now I'm stuck. I was expecting to find a screw under the cap but instead I found this:

[image]

The bathroom faucets look the same. I think there are threads for a screw in the center, and it looks flat at the bottom. The rest of the handle is stuck pretty tight, and I've used channellocks to twist in both directions and a screwdriver to help leverage it straight off but without success.

I haven't been able to find any markings on either the shower or bathroom faucets to help me identify them. The showerhead doesn't look original (brand: Interbath) and the house was built in 2004. This sink is Kohler, toilet is American Standard, other bathrooms have Delta and a Grohe faucet so we're all over the place.

Any help to identify the faucet and/or take remove the rest of the handle would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I appreciate the suggestions so far!...but I'm still stuck. I pulled on the handle as hard as I could and it now have a bit of play (about 2mm). But something is stopping its removal -- almost like there's a set screw inside the handle. The inside brass gear with a hole seems to pull out with the handle (but only those 2mm). The hole seems to be flat at the bottom but seems to have screw threads inside. I've added another pic, taken at an angle. Thanks again!

[image]

Comment: what is inside that hole ? was that a push/pull handle ?

Comment: Unless you can find/see a hole/screw on the bottom, I might just try pulling it off.  The knob is on a spline shaft and I do not see any screw in it.

Comment: I think there are plumbing pullers(like gear pullers) that are made for that type.

Comment: I cannot make out what is inside the shaft in the center. Is there a screw head of some kind? There is a large O-ring showing on the edge and hanging out on the right side. It may be binding.  Push the O-ring back in on the right. Try unscrewing the handle.Try prying against the inside disc. Try gripping the central shaft with needlenose pliers and pulling.

Comment: That looks splined, like you should be able to just pull the handle off.  Maybe some kind of slide hammer puller?

Comment: So there are threads inside the central brass shaft. Are these threads left handed or right handed? If the threads are left handed I can imagine that one is supposed to thread in a tool (a bolt) counter CW until it is tight then keep turning CCW and this unscrews the central tube which is holding the parts together.